# Netherlands and Holland tag synonym?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

We currently have this as a synonym - but Holland is actually an area within the Netherlands; the two are not one and the same.  Thoughts? Should we remove this synonym?

Comment: In russian Netherlands and Holland it is the same :P

Comment: It's actually quite easy once it's explained.  Great Britain is the big island: England, Scotland and Wales.  Three separate countries. Then add in Northern Ireland and some of the other little ones and you get United Kingdom.  Ireland is a separate country completely and shouldn't be included in any of that stuff :)

Comment: One could *probably* synomym Great Britain and United Kingdom - it's not techincally true, but colloquially so many people get it wrong that it's probably ok.  And if someone is travelling around the UK they may well want tags for it.  However, I'd still keep individual tags for England, Scotland and Wales as they're distinct in their own right.  Also tags for Jersey, Guernsey, Shetland Islands and more, haha

Comment: "Holland" and "Netherlands" are *de facto* the same for dumb foreigners like us so synonymize them until it becomes a problem, and it may never become a problem. As for a certain selection of islands subdivided into various types of regional entities west of France, let them overlap I say. If and when anyone uses a tag perfectly wrongly somebody may correct each one. Trying to organize them in advance though will be an exercize in futility and pain.

Comment: Probably so far just because of people's travels and the questions, I guess?

Comment: Interestingly (or not), Dutch people themselves tend to say “Holland” when speaking of the whole country in a foreign language (never in Dutch of course where it's “Nederland” or “NL”).